# Hacker Rank Frequency Queries

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

I am doing the Hacker Rank Frequency Queries question and all my test cases pass but one for Time limit exceeded. What can I do to make my program more efficient.

```
static List<Integer> freqQuery(List<List<Integer>> queries) {
    List<Integer> freqCount = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(List q : queries){
        int op = (Integer)q.get(0);
        int num = (Integer)q.get(1);
        
        switch (op){
            case 1:
                if(data.get(num) == null){
                    //Add new value to hashmap
                    data.put(num, 1);
                }else{
                    data.put(num, data.get(num) + 1);
                }
            break;
            case 2:
                if(data.get(num) != null){
                    if(data.get(num) == 0){
                        //data.remove(num);
                    }else{
                       data.put(num, data.get(num) - 1); 
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                if(data.containsValue(num)){
                    freqCount.add(1);
                }else{
                    freqCount.add(0);
                }
            break;
        }

    }
    
    return freqCount;
}
```

Comment: Why not make a list of the operations inside your main loop, and estimate the performance of each? Does one look a lot slower than the others?

Comment: Can you link to the original Hack Rank question? The one I found it doesn't look like this would work at all.

Comment: The `time complexity` of  `boolean containsValue(Object value)` is `O(n)`. *You can make it more efficient if you make that check in `case 3` in `O(1)`.*

Comment: @Grzegorz this question would be even worse fit over there than here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183/31260)**

Comment: My bad @gnat, noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time complexity` of `boolean containsValue(Object value)` of class `HashMap<K,V>` is *`O(n)`*. *If in `case 3`, you can do a constant time look up - `O(1)`, your code will be quite efficient.*

*According to the constraints mentioned in the problem statement:*

- Maximum number of queries:

  > `1 <= q <= 10^5`
- Maximum possible value of x, y and z:

  > `1 <= x, y, z <= 10^9`

In order to check *if any integer is present in your data structure whose frequency is exactly z* in `O(1)`, ***you can use an simple array***.

If there is an element `e` in your array at an index `z`, then it will denote that there are `e` elements in your data structure with `frequency z`. The *index* of your array denotes ***frequency*** and the *value at that index* denotes ***the number of elements in your data structure with that frequency***. You can call this array as `nestedFrequency` since it stores the *frequency of frequencies*. The `size` of the array will be `100001`. *Since the maximum number of possible queries are 100000, there can be no element whose frequency is greater than 100000.*

**Pseudocode:**

```
for i = 1 to queries.length
    int choice = queries[i][0]
    int number = queries[i][1]
    
    switch (choice)
        case 1:
            Add the number in hashMap and map it to a value of 0 if not already 
            present.

            //Obtain the previous frequency of that number in hashMap
            int oldFre = hashMap.get(number)
            
            //Update the nested frequency array
            nestedFrequency[oldFre]--
            nestedFrequency[oldFre+1]++

            //Update the frequency of that number in hashmap
            Increase the frequency of that number in hashMap 
        case 2:
            if there is a mapping present of the given number in hashMap
                //Obtain the previous frequency of that number in hashMap
                int oldFre = hashMap.get(number)

                //Update the nested frequency array
                nestedFrequency[oldFre]--
                if (oldFre-1 != 0) nestedFrequency[oldFre-1]++
                
                //Update the frequency of that number in hashmap
                if (oldFre-1 == 0) remove the mapping of that element in hashmap
                else decrease its old frequency
        case 3:
            if number < 100001 and nestedFrequncy[number] > 0
                print 1
            else 
                print 0
```

I hope I have helped you. *Do comment for any further problems.*